# Cannot install postgresql on Wine

Tags: wine

I do the following. I run the installer downloaded from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).

```
$ ./postgresql-9.6.20-1-windows-x64.exe
```

Opens the installer. If I click through everything as normal, I hit "The database cluster initialisation failed" detailed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656410/postgresql-installation-failed) SE question. Following the answers, I attempt to change the installation path. However, this happens.

[image]

In the terminal, I see

```
06fc:fixme:icacls:main This is dummy icacls, not performing ACL manipulations
06fc:fixme:icacls:main stub: "C:\\windows\\System32\\icacls.exe" "C:\\users\\USER\\Temp/postgresql_installer_b335608a0c" "/inheritance:r"
070c:fixme:icacls:main This is dummy icacls, not performing ACL manipulations
070c:fixme:icacls:main stub: "C:\\windows\\System32\\icacls.exe" "C:\\users\\USER\\Temp/postgresql_installer_b335608a0c" "/T" "/Q" "/grant" "HOSTNAME\\USER:(OI)(CI)F"
071c:fixme:icacls:main This is dummy icacls, not performing ACL manipulations
071c:fixme:icacls:main stub: "C:\\windows\\System32\\icacls.exe" "." "/save" "C:\\users\\USER\\Temp/postgresql_installer_b335608a0c/aclfile"
```

Indicating perhaps something wrong with permissions. I'm not sure what to do.

```
Operating System: Arch Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.20.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.78.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.6-arch1-1
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 23.4 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520
```

I'm running wine 5.22.

Comment: Why are you installing it on Wine?

Comment: I am installing another windows application that requires it.

Comment: Can’t the other Windows application connect to a non-Windows PostgreSQL server?

Comment: @StephenKitt Not sure, the other application's installer just tells me it can't find a PostgreSQL and fails. I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL.